# Why does python gcloud discovery api for creating instance return None?

Tags: python, google-compute-engine, google-api-python-client, google-apis-explorer

## Existing documentation

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/insert

states that the return type of the call would be a dictionary of multiple status values. In addition, even their [python examples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/compute/api/create_instance.py) shows that the return type is of type dict.

## What actually happens

What I've experienced is that the call actually gives me `None`:

```
config = {
        'name': "test-machine",
        'machineType': "zones/us-central1-c/machineTypes/foobar",
        'disks': [
            {
                'boot': True,
                'autoDelete': True,
                'deviceName': "test-machine",
                ...
        }
    }

operation = compute.instances().insert(project=PROJECT_NAME, zone=ZONE, body=config).execute()
wait_for_operation(compute, PROJECT_NAME, ZONE, operation["name"])
```

The `wait_for_operation()` function is taken straight off of the python examples:

```
def wait_for_operation(compute, project, zone, operation):
    print('Waiting for operation to finish...')
    while True:
        result = compute.zoneOperations().get(
            project=project,
            zone=zone,
            operation=operation).execute()

        if result['status'] == 'DONE':
            print("done.")
            if 'error' in result:
                raise Exception(result['error'])
            return result

        time.sleep(1)
```

and yet, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gcloud_playground.py", line 113, in <module>
    wait_for_operation(compute, PROJECT_NAME, ZONE, operation["name"])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

What actually happens is that **my instance is successfully created, but I would have no idea whether it is successfully created or not.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I figured it out. It was a malformed portion of my JSON that somehow screwed up the gcloud discovery api.

I wrote in the configs:

```
"tags" : [ "tag1", "tag2", ... ]
```

instead of

```
"tags" : { "items" : [ "tag1", "tag2", ... ] }
```

which is a really subtle and stupid error that gcloud failed to pick up.

For anyone seeing this, **your config is wrong and the discovery api is bad. If you get a None it's the same as if you get a `googleapiclient.errors.HttpError`!**